# "Invalid parameter type" (numpy.int64) when inserting rows with executemany()

Tags: python, sql-server, numpy, pyodbc, freetds

I try to insert bunch of data to database

```
insert_list = [(1,1,1,1,1,1),(2,2,2,2,2,2),(3,3,3,3,3,3),....] #up to 10000 tuples in this list

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=xxxxx;DATABASE=xxxx;UID=xx;PWD=xx;TDS_Version=7.0')
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "insert into ScanEMAxEMAHistoryDay(SecurityNumber, EMA1, EMA2, CrossType, DayCross, IsLocalMinMax) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

cursor.executemany(sql, insert_list)
```

> cursor.executemany(sql, insert_list)
>
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=4 param-type=numpy.int64', 'HY105')

reduce to 100 tuples:

```
cursor.executemany(sql, insert_list[:100])
```

> cursor.executemany(sql, insert_list[:100])
>
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=4 param-type=numpy.int64', 'HY105')
>       cursor.executemany(sql, insert_list[:100])

reduce to 5 tuples:

```
cursor.executemany(sql, insert_list[:5])
conn.commit()
```

**This can insert to database**

I have try to:

```
sql = 'SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=50*1024*1024'
cursor.execute(sql)
```

before excutemany() but it have an error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]'GLOBAL' is not a recognized SET option. (195) (SQLExecDirectW)")

How did i solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your problem is not with the volume of data *per se*, it is that some of your tuples contain `numpy.int64` values that cannot be used directly as parameter values for your SQL statement. For example,

```python
a = numpy.array([10, 11, 12], dtype=numpy.int64)
params = (1, 1, a[1], 1, 1, 1)
crsr.execute(sql, params)
```

will throw

> ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=2 param-type=numpy.int64', 'HY105')

because the third parameter value is a `numpy.int64` element from your numpy array `a`. Converting that value with `int()` will avoid the issue:

```python
a = numpy.array([10, 11, 12], dtype=numpy.int64)
params = (1, 1, int(a[1]), 1, 1, 1)
crsr.execute(sql, params)
```

By the way, the reason that

```python
sql = 'SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=50*1024*1024'
cursor.execute(sql)
```

didn't work is that `max_allowed_packet` is a MySQL setting that does not have any meaning for Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: How can I do this with a Pandas DataFrame? I've tried df[col].astype(int) for every col but still no joy.

Comment: @MattCamp - I just tried a simple test using `df.values.tolist()` and it worked for me. If you require further assistance you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: yea I got it to work.. had some issue that it was not allowing me to commit the dataframe because there were duplicates in a field there shouldnt be and then when I tried to do fewer records it threw the above error.. when I just changed the duplicate records to test things out it worked. thanks

Comment: When getting the "Invalid parameter type" error, is there a good way to tell which of the values are causing the error? i.e. when have a large number of columns it isn't always obvious which one is causing the error...

Answer (score 5):

I did the same as Robert; I converted everything to string. In my case, it was a pandas data frame that I casted to string type:

```
data = pandas.read_json(...)
data.astype(str).to_sql(...)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

If the data you are retrieving includes URLs, you may get a "unknown protocol" error (or something like that). If you get this error even after casting to string type, try using `StringIO` **instead**:

```
import requests
from io import StringIO
...
data = pandas.read_json(StringIO(response.text))
```

where `response` is an instance of object `Response` from the `requests` library and its attribute `text` contains the json text data.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone out there reading this, it was driving me up the wall.

My eventual solution was to convert all variables to 'str' and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when passing parameters into a SQL INSERT statement using `pyodbc`. As mentioned by Robert, just converting the variable to string worked.

Example:
Syntax - str()

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Table ([col1],[col2],[col3]...])VALUES(?,'test',?)", str(value1), str(value3))
```