# Quandl + Python: The date column not "working"

Tags: python, quandl

I am trying to get some data through the API from quandl but the date column doesn't seem to work the same level as the other columns. E.g. when I use the following code:

```
data = quandl.get("WIKI/KO", trim_start = "2000-12-12", trim_end =
"2014-12-30", authtoken=quandl.ApiConfig.api_key) 

print(data['Open'])
```

I end up with the below result

> Date
>
> 2000-12-12    57.69
>
> 2000-12-13    57.75
>
> 2000-12-14    56.00
>
> 2000-12-15    55.00
>
> 2000-12-18    54.00

E.g. date appearing along with the 'Open' column. And when I try to directly include Date like this:

```
print(data[['Open','Date']]),
```

it says Date doesn't exist as a column. So I have two questions: (1) How do I make Date an actual column and (2) How do I select only the 'Open' column (and thus not the dates).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why `print(data['Open'])` show dates even though `Date` is not a column*:

`quandle.get` returns a [Pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#minutes-to-pandas), whose *index* is a DatetimeIndex.
Thus, to access the dates you would use `data.index` instead of `data['Date']`.

---

> (1) How do I make Date an actual column

If you wish to make the DatetimeIndex into a column, call [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
data = data.reset_index()
print(data[['Open', 'Date']])
```

---

> (2) How do I select only the 'Open' column (and thus not the dates)

To obtain a NumPy array of values without the index, use [`data['Open'].values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html).
(All Pandas Series and DataFrames have `Index`s (that's Pandas' raison d'être!), so the only way obtain the values without the index is to convert the Series or DataFrame to a different kind of object, like a NumPy array.)

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask you one more question? I would like to insert the price into an SQL table and I have setted up the string correct. But the format still seems to not work. Receiving the following error "pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=numpy.ndarray', 'HY105')". How would I have to "manipulate" price so I can insert it into an SQL table?

Comment: That looks like [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41973933/190597) (found by googling "pyodbc NumPy array Invalid parameter type"). To avoid the error, try converting the NumPy array to a Python list  by calling its [`tolist()` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html): `data['Open'].values.tolist()`. If that does not solve the problem, please one a new question which shows the table schema, the SQL, and python code you are using.

Comment: By comparison with the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41973933/190597) it appears you might be trying to insert the entire array into a single table record. To resolve that issue -- if it really is the issue -- it would be helpful to see your SQL and python code first.

Comment: Not sure how to format it, but I only have one value using the following code:
"price = sta[:1]
print(price)
cur.execute ("Insert into PG (price) values (?)", price)". Also tried "sta = data['Open'].values" but that didn't work either. If I just set price = 55 (as an example), it works.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what the situation is. (Such as the value of `price` and `sta` when you call `cur.execute`. And are you getting the same error message with everything you've tried!?.) Please post a **new question** with all the details.