# Load pandas dataframe to SQL Server 2012

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I try to load pandas dataframe to SQL Server. The dataframe has following columns:

- userId  - int
- saleId - int
- regTime - int
- countryId - int

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
for index, row in users.iterrows():
     cursor.execute('INSERT INTO [dbo].[users]([userId],[saleId],[regTime],[countryId]) values (?,?,?,?)', 
                     row['userId'], 
                     row['saleId'], 
                     row['regTime'],
                     row['countryId'])
     cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

But i have the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-383c1873cad8> in <module>
      4                     row['saleId'],
      5                     row['regTime'],
----> 6                     row['countryId'])
      7     cnxn.commit()
      8 cursor.close()

ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=numpy.int64', 'HY105')
```

countryId column has values from 0 to 9 (codes)

How can i correct it?

Comment: Please try this instead of the for loop and let me know if you face any issues `data_frame.to_sql(name='target_table_name', con=cnxn, if_exists = 'replace' )`

Comment: I tried it, but i have another error: pyodbc.interfaceerror) ('im002', '[im002]

Comment: Can you share the complete error line? Also double check you are able to connect to database and execute some query `cursor.execute("select * from xxx")` and you have write access

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973933/invalid-parameter-type-numpy-int64-when-inserting-rows-with-executemany